# how to write Hibernate NamedQuery left join with case when?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

given example tables

```
table: acknowledgement
==============
id,post_id,user_id


table: post
==============
id,content

table: attachment
==============
id,post_id,name
```

and also

in my post class, got a column

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=attachment.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Set<attachment> file=null;
```

---

when user login, the system will have the user id, therefore my NativeQuery will be

```
select *,case when p.id is null then false else true end as ack from post 
left join acknowledgement a on p.id =  a.post_id where a.user_id = :id
```

Data:

```
==================================
= id , content , acknowledgement =
==================================
= 1  , hello   ,  true           =
==================================
= 5  , hello 5 ,  false          =
==================================
```

my questions is

1. how to convert the native query it to HQL in namedquery from this case?
2. is it possible using annotate like above one to many to solve ***case when***?

note: i using hibernate 4.1.6 final